# Using a JSF converter in a custom tag

Tags: icefaces-1.8

I have a custom XHTML tag redefining `ice:inputText`.
I need to map the converter attribute into it.

Adding `converter="#{converter}"` to the tag, inside the inputText, seems not to have the right effect.

When I use the tag specifying `converter="XMLGregorianCalendarConverter"` I get the following error:

```
Problem in renderResponse: Cannot convert XMLGregorianCalendarConverter of type class java.lang.String to interface javax.faces.convert.Converter
```

The above converter is correectly defined in my global faces-config.xml.

What could be causing this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in facelets. 
See issue: http://java.net/jira/browse/FACELETS-273

I hit the same bug today...

using the exact name in my tag resolves it. (passing parameter doesn't work)